# Programmatically select an md-select option

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have an angular-material `md-select` element with multiple selection which I define like this:

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedTypes"
           ng-change="typesChanged()"
           multiple
           ng-disabled="availableTypes.length == 0">
           <md-option ng-repeat="type in availableTypes" ng-value="{{type}}">
              {{type.displayName}}
           </md-option>
</md-select>
```

During the load of the controller I load an array of available types from the server and then set the `selectedTypes` to `availableTypes[0]` (after the `availableTypes` is loaded) as follows:

```
$scope.promise = Types.query(query, function (types) { // Types is a $resource
        $scope.availableTypes = types;
        $scope.selectedTypes = [$scope.availableTypes[0]];
});
```

Because `selectedTypes` is the model of the `md-select` directive, I expected that it will make the first selection option become selected. But it didn't work. I couldn't find in the documentation any way to programmatically select an element in the `md-select`.

Comment: So you want some predefined values selected in `md-select` whenever page loads. right ?

Comment: @nextt1 - Exactly. But also there will be situations in which I would like to change the selection programmatically due to other state changes (not only page load). So I prefer to find a solution that is not only relevant for page-load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `md-select` with `multiple` then model you bind to `md-select` must be an array and you defined in your code like this.

```
$scope.selectedTypes = [$scope.availableTypes[0]];
```

which doesn't represent a array. You just need to add the value you specify in you `md-option` to that model.

```
$scope.selectedTypes = []; //defined array
$scope.selectedTypes.push($scope.availableTypes[0]);
```

Check out following pen for working example.

http://codepen.io/next1/pen/qZKzMy

In you code you used `ng-value="{{type}}`. Since `ng-value` is angular directive you should not use `{{ }}`. Check out the offical Doc about [ngValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I have tried this as well and it doesn't work. I assume the difference between my code and yours is the use of a callback that uses the result from the server in my code VS a linear, no callback flow in your example. Do you have an idea about that?

Comment: I think since you are using `ng-value` you won't need `{{ }}` as it is an angular directive. That may be a reason if you are not getting results as desired. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue

Comment: You're right! That was the problem! Can you please edit your answer to include this before I'm accepting it? (You can leave the example, I think it will be good for future reference to other people)

Comment: No problem at all. :)